Не могу записать на папку в сетевой шаре Synology
Дано задача, бэкапить базу 1С на MSSQL на NAS хранилище Synology,
который расположенный по адресу
\\192.168.168.8.
Есть папка на Synology по пути: \\192.168.168.8\Backup\ITS24 - на папки есть права на чтение и запись, у мой учетки  который запускаю сей скрипт.
Локально отработает на папку C:\testbackup
При запуске с указанием - \\192.168.168.8\Backup\ITS24 разбивается ошибкой нет доступа
Вопрос, как реализовать запись на Synology?
@echo off

set SQLServer=IT__SUPPORT\SQLEXPRESS
set Database=TESTDB
set BackupPath=\\192.168.168.8\Backup\ITS24

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /value') do set "dt=%%I"
set DateTime=%dt:~0,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%_%dt:~8,2%-%dt:~10,2%-%dt:~12,2%

set BackupFile=%BackupPath%\%Database%_%DateTime%.bak


sqlcmd -S %SQLServer% -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%Database%] TO DISK='%BackupFile%' WITH INIT"

if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
  echo Ошибка при выполнении резервного копирования.
) else (
  echo Резервная копия успешно создана: %BackupFile%
)

 pause



у sqlcmd есть права на запись в эту папку?
